# Hope to open a webview in slide 2 without a button

Tags: android, webview, android-fragments

No other way of asking this. i am using android studio, i have set up an app with scrollable swipe tabs, ive set 4 tabs, i wish to have a webpage load in tab 2, i have a webview class and a internet class, i have set manifest to allow internet, but i have t have a button on my layout file and set an onlcik listner to load my webpge, what i want to know is how do i load the webview when i swipe to page 2 without using a button

code follows

```
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phones, container, false);

            return view;

        }

        if ((getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2)) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webload, container, false);

            Button webButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.view7);

            webButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(getActivity(), Internet.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
```

`

Comment: any info at all would be great please guys.. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd implement separate classes for different fragments. When you will have a lot of code for each fragment of the tabs, your code will be a bit a mess and difficult to read and maintain.

Then, if you want to display a webpage within your app (so no browser opened), in your fragment, put a webview in the layout, then in the code get that webview like other views by id, and load the URL you need.

Here official documentation about how webview works: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html